# What's the difference between "Requires full screen" and "Hide status bar"

Tags: xcode

In the general settings for an iOS app in Xcode, you have 2 checkboxes:[image: checkboxes]

What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Hide status bar**

The name of the check box is pretty self explanatory.
To hide the status bar from your apps launch screen you need to tick the Hide status bar checkbox under the `Project Target > General > Deployment Info`

**Requires Full screen**

IOS 9+ supports resizable apps with multi-window support. Unless you are re-writing your app to support multi-window, you will be requiring 'Full screen'. This is a hint to iOS that you do not support multi-window, and basically makes iOS 9+ work like previous versions in this regard.